# Does any one know how to view three imageview in just one click of button using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

**Imageactivity.java**

```
 package com.example.Imagebuttonactivity; 
    import android.os.Bundle;    import android.app.Activity;   import
    android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Imagebuttonactivity extends Activity {



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.imagebuttonactivity, menu);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           //set up main content view
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            configureImageButton();
    }

    private void configureImageButton() {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id. imageButton1);
        btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
            public void onClick(VIew v) {


            // Change image on botton
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id. imageView1);
        btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageview4);


           ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id. imageView2);
        btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageview5);


           ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id. imageView3);
        btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageview6);


            }
        });
    }    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. You are going to need to provide a little more detail if you want help. Like what exactly is the problem you are having. Just posting code and a title saying, "How do I do something?" isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

These would happen so fast that you would only see the last image.

Use some kind of delay and invalidate the button between image updates.

```
      btn.invalidate():
```

Check out CountDownTimer, you could start it in the onClick and then on each tick change the image.

Comment: i dont know how to use that incalidate and delay sir :(